# KnexJS loop of queries

Tags: node.js, promise, knex.js

I'm very new with Node, KnexJS and promises and I'm trying to build a simple loop that queries items and then adds the pictures associated with them.

I looked at this answer and while it teaches a few things I don't think it works for my case: [Knex Transaction with Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957032/knex-transaction-with-promises#)

So far I have this:

```html
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  knex('parts').where(req.query)
    .orderBy('date_updated', 'DESC')
    .then(function(data){

      for (var k in data) {
        knex('photos')
          .select()
          .where('part_id', data[k].id)
          .then(function(photos){
            data[k].photos = photos;
          });
      }
      return data;

    })
    .then(function(data){
      res.render('parts/index', { title: 'Express', data: data, query: req.query });
    });
});
```

Which is obviously wrong, but I just don't know the approach in these cases.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `Promise.all`

Comment: `Promise.all` (concurrent) or `Promise.each` sequential depending on what you'd like.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the iterator is sequential, the array of promises passed to each may very well be concurrent: see comment http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html#comment-2661321645

Answer (score 3):

Adding to IvanSF's answer, you can simply wrap a `Promise.all()` around that, to then `res.send()` the response. Like so:

```
Promise.all(rows.map(row => {
    return knex('table')
        .select('*').where('row_id', row.id)
        .then(table => {
            row.table = table;
            return row;
        });
})).then(response => {
    res.send(response);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I used .map to get the desired effect.

```js
    .map(function(row) {
      return knex('photos')
        .select()
        .where('part_id', row.id)
        .then(function(photos) {
          row.photos = photos;
          return row;
        });
    })
```