# How to pass multiple values to one parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, knex.js

Currently i have done code to accept one category_id in the param and return output base on category_id.

```
if ('category' in params) {
        assert.number(params.category, 'params.category')

        const { category: category_id } = params
        query = query.where('category.id', category_id)
      }
```

Now i want to pass multiple values to category_id and return result for all category_id's.

I will pass like this, **category_id=1,2,3**

Can someone helps me to fix this?

Comment: you need to pass category_id in Array for multiple values like  const { category: [1,2,3] }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704936/knexjs-loop-of-queries/43953308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereIn

```
query.whereIn('category.id', [1, 2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Improve [Ростислав Борніцький](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9109247/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) answer little bit,

```
if ('category' in params) {
        assert.array(params.category, 'params.category')

        const { category: category_id } = params
        query = query.whereIn('category.id', category_id)
      }
```