# Commit/rollback a knex transaction using async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, knex.js

I'm test driving the [ES7 async/await proposal](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/) using [this module](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) to emulate it. I'm trying to make [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) transactions play well with them, as a starting point.

Example code:

```
async function transaction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    knex.transaction(function(err, result){
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Start transaction from this call

insert: async (function(db, data) {
 const trx = await(transaction());
 const idUser = await(user.insertData(trx, data));

 return {
    idCidUserstomer: idUser
  }
})
```

How can I `commit()` or `rollback()` if a transaction succeeds or fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of this [Knex Transaction with Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957032/knex-transaction-with-promises/22964163#22964163), it looks like it should be along these lines:

```
// assume `db` is a knex instance

insert: async (function(db, data) {
  const trx = db.transaction();
  try {
    const idUser = await(user.insertData(trx, data));
    trx.commit();
  } catch (error) {
    trx.rollback();
    throw error;
  }

  return {
    idUser: idUser
  }
})
```

Comment: 1 note here - For some strange reason, putting the `return { idCustomer: idCustomer}` part inside the `try` block makes it tick just fine, otherwise it hangs, as in the part below the `try..catch` doesn't run

Comment: Try using `await` on trx.commit and trx.rollback, otherwise not too sure.

Comment: `Try using await on trx.commit/trx.rollback` - didn't work but I'll dig around and post a comment here.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides did you come up with any answer to the hanging issue?

Comment: @serkandemirel0420 Unfortunately, no - if you figure it out I'd be happy to know though

Answer (score 8):

You might be able to achieve this with something similar to this

```
function createTransaction() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    return knex.transaction(resolve);
  });
}

async function() {
  const trx = await createTransaction();
  ...
  trx.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
async function() {
  await knex.transaction( async (trx) => {
     ...
     trx.commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You should not call commit inside of .transaction. it will automatically do that for you when the promise resolves.