# Knex Transaction - Using Await - Not executing 2nd SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, knex.js

I am using knex `0.19.4` in node js `10.x`. I have 2 SQL statements - Insert and Update which has to happen as a transaction.

```
// Using Var, so that below code has access to this variable
var sqlStageInsert = kx('stage').insert({
  officeid: 'OFF000',
  taskid: 'T002',
});


var sqlTaskPcUpdate = kx('task')
  .update({ pc: 100})
  .where('task.taskno', taskno)
  .limit(1);
```

1st Try - 2nd SQL `sqlTaskPcUpdate` Not getting Executed

```
const sqlUpdateInsert = kx.transaction(function (trx) {
  sqlStageInsert.transacting(trx)
    .then(function () {
      console.log(sqlTaskPcUpdate.toString()); // This is outputing correct SQL
      return sqlTaskPcUpdate.transacting(trx);
    })
    .then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback);
});
await sqlUpdateInsert;
```

2nd Try - Getting error `Transaction query already complete`. This is based on [Commit/rollback a knex transaction using async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40581040/4050261)

```
await kx.transaction(async (trx) => {
  try {
    await sqlStageInsert.transacting(trx);
    await sqlTaskPcUpdate.transacting(trx);
    trx.commit();
  } catch (error) {
    trx.rollback();
    throw error;
  }
});
```

Comment: `.transaction` looks callback-based, not Promise-based..?

Comment: It still looks callback-based? Are you sure `.transaction` returns a Promise?

Comment: Yes, `.transaction` returns Promise

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try inserting the data in **stage** table first and then retrieve a common value which belongs to both the table for applying in where class of updating **task** table(Assuming both the table contain any one common column having same data).

Please note that as per knexjs.org website, knex.transaction() uses returning statement with respect to PostgreSQL to insert/ update more than one table to maintain consistency, however MySQL won't support transaction due to which I'm using return values in below code.

FYR, http://knexjs.org/#Transactions

Please refer below code snippet for your reference :

```js
db.transaction(trx => {
  trx.insert({
    officeid: 'OFF000',
    taskid: 'T002'
  })
  .into('stage')
  .then(() => {
    return trx('stage').where({taskid}).then(resp => resp[0].taskno)
  })
  .then(stageTaskno => {
    return trx('task')
          .update({pc: 100})
          .where({stageTaskno})
          .limit(1)
          .then(resp => {
            resp.json(resp)
          })
  })
  .then(trx.commit)
  .catch(trx.rollback)
});
```

hope this is helpful, cheers!