# Knex.js multiple chained queries

Tags: node.js, express, promise, es6-promise, knex.js

I'm currently working on a project in express and I'm using knex.js to handle migrations and queries.

I'm still trying to grasp the concept of promises and how I can run multiple queries with knex.

I have the following code which inserts a new record into my database, this is located in my `Unit model` file.

```
this.addUnit = function(unit_prefixV, unit_nameV, unit_descriptionV, profile_id) {
         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             knex.insert({ unit_prefix: unit_prefixV, unit_name: unit_nameV, unit_description: unit_descriptionV })
                .into('units').then(function(unit) {
                    resolve(unit)
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    reject(error)
                })
         })
    }
```

In my `routes.js` file I then call this on a post request, like so:

```
app.post('/dashboard/unit/add', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
        let postErrors = []
        if (req.body.unit_name.trim() == "") {
            postErrors.push('Unit name cannot be empty.')
        }

        if (req.body.unit_prefix.trim() == "") {
            postErrors.push('Unit prefix cannot be empty.')
        }

        if (req.body.unit_description.trim() == "") {
            postErrors.push('Unit description cannot be empty.')
        }

        if (postErrors.length > 0) {
            res.render('addUnit', { errors: postErrors, user: req.user })
        } else {
            unitModel.addUnit(req.body.unit_prefix.trim(), req.body.unit_name.trim(), req.body.unit_description.trim(), req.session.passport.user.id).then(function(unit) {
                res.redirect('/dashboard')
            })
        }
    })
```

This successfully inserts a new record into my `units` table, however, I would like to select the user id from the users table with the matching `profile_id` and then insert another record into my `users_units` table. All within the `this.addUnit` function.

For reference my `users` table consists of:

- id
- google_id

my `users_units` table consists of:

- user_id
- unit_id

I've made an attempt to chain the queries but it only executed the initial insert query and not the others. Here is that rather ugly attempt:

```
this.addUnit = function(unit_prefixV, unit_nameV, unit_descriptionV, profile_id) {
         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             knex.insert({ unit_prefix: unit_prefixV, unit_name: unit_nameV, unit_description: unit_descriptionV })
                .into('units').then(function(unit) {
                    knex('users').where({ "google_id": profile_id }).select('id').then(function(uid) {
                        knex.insert({ user_id: uid, unit_id: unit }).into('users_units').then(function(user_units) {
                            resolve(user_unit)
                        }).catch(function(error) {
                            reject(error)
                        })
                        resolve(uid)
                    })
                    console.log(unit)
                    resolve(unit)
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    reject(error)
                })
         })
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Here is some page explaining how to chain promises, knex promises is no different https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises#chaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there. There are just a few simple point to grasp :

- A Promise can be reolved only once
- An explicit Promise is not needed anyway because a naturally occurring promise can be returned
- `return` a Promise at each stage ...
- ... until the innermost stage, from which the returned value is the finally delivered result.
- Errors needn't be eplicitly handled unless you want to inject your own custom error messages or take remedial action.

Having taken all that on board, you might write :

```
this.addUnit = function(unit_prefixV, unit_nameV, unit_descriptionV, profile_id) {
    return knex.insert({ 'unit_prefix':unit_prefixV, 'unit_name':unit_nameV, 'unit_description':unit_descriptionV }).into('units')
 // ^^^^^^
    .then(function(unit) {
        return knex('users').where({ 'google_id':profile_id }).select('id')
     // ^^^^^^
        .then(function(uid) {
            return knex.insert({ 'unit_id':unit, 'user_id':uid }).into('users_units')
         // ^^^^^^
            .then(function(user_units) {
                return { 'unit_id':unit, 'user_id':uid, 'user_units':user_units };
             // ^^^^^^
            });
        });
    });
}
```

If the caller is interested only in success/failure of the process and not the full `{ unit, uid, user_units }` object, then the innermost `.then()` can be omitted :

```
this.addUnit = function(unit_prefixV, unit_nameV, unit_descriptionV, profile_id) {
    return knex.insert({ 'unit_prefix':unit_prefixV, 'unit_name':unit_nameV, 'unit_description':unit_descriptionV }).into('units')
    .then(function(unit) {
        return knex('users').where({ 'google_id':profile_id }).select('id')
        .then(function(uid) {
            return knex.insert({ 'unit_id':unit, 'user_id':uid }).into('users_units');
        });
    });
}
```

The promise returned by `.addUnit()` will still deliver `user_units`, which the caller can use or ignore.

There's a major proviso to these solutions (and others); a multi-stage update query like this should really be wrapped in a [transaction](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-transacting) - ie something that allows earlier stages to be rolled back. Otherwise a failure part way through is likely to leave the database in some indeterminate state. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22964163/3478010) is as good a starting point as any.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. One thing is I get the error `Unhandled rejection Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: '[object Object]' for column 'user_id' at row 1`

Comment: Looks like the inner `knex.insert()` is wrongly constructed. `uid` appears to be Object but the query expects Integer. Could be a consequence of a mistake at the previous stage - `knex('users').where(...)`? Sorry I can't be more definitive.

Comment: Nesting promises is a terrible idea and a well known [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803744/10094651). They should always be chained.

Comment: @denkquer, a flat chain is indeed preferred, *when achievable*.
For that reason, nesting is *not always* a terrible idea; in fact quite the opposite.
If you look carefully at my code, you will see that I chose *not* to flatten for [a very good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/3478010). The innermost `knex.insert()` needs `unit` to be in scope. This would not happen if the chain was flattened.
BTW, you have linked to the "explicit-construction anti-pattern", which is a very different scenario.